# S-matrix and derivative interaction

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering

I just read in some lecture notes that formally we can write the S Matrix as: 
$$S=T(e^{-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} H_{int}dt}) $$
Where $T$ is the normal product and $H_{int}$ is in the interaction picture.
 For non derivative interaction $H_{int}=-L_{int}=-\int d^3x\, \mathcal{L}_{int}$, so:
$$S=T(e^{\int \mathcal{L}_{int}d^4x}) $$
Then the author says that this last expression is valid also in the general case of derivative interaction. I want to know if you know some references for this; i was think that maybe it's could be as in scalar QED where the additionals terms (coming from the derivative part of the lagrangian) don't play any role in the perturbative expansion.

Thanks for all!

Comment: Which lecture notes?

Comment: [Here](http://theory.fi.infn.it/casalbuoni/tesi.pdf) at pag. 145